# C# add COM reference to Class Library

Tags: c#, com, dependencies, class-library

I am trying to create a Class Library which uses preexisting COM library. When using "Console application" type for project, all I need to do is to R-click "references" and choose "Add COM model reference". When using "Class Library" type, no such option appears. I can only reference "project" or "shared project". How to add COM dependency to Class Library?

Comment: You can add a COM Reference for C# .NET Framework and C# .NET 5/Core projects, Console or Class Library. There's no "Add COM model reference" menu. Are you using Visual Studio or other IDE? Please detail what you're doing exactly.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio, and this is right, I was using it in Polish, and translated what was shown. When I changed language to English it was "Add COM reference". Also you are right, my console application was using .NET Core 5.0, and my Class Library was using .NET Standard 2.0 .

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my console application was usint .NET Core 5.0, which allowed to add COM dependency, and Class Library was using .NET Standard 2.0, which did not. After changing this so that both used .NET Core, it worked.